# Is cnosdb will crash after meaningless input?

Tags: database, cnosdb

```
$ ./target/release/cnosdb-cli
CnosDB CLI v2.3.2
Input arguments: Args { host: "localhost", port: 8902, user: "root", password: None, private_key_path: None, database: "public", tenant: "cnosdb", precision: None, target_partitions: None, stream_trigger_interval: None, data_path: None, file: [], rc: None, format: Table, quiet: false, write_line_protocol: None, use_ssl: false, use_unsafe_ssl: false, cacert: [], chunked: false }
public ❯ 1;
thread 'main' panicked at 'byte index 3 is out of bounds of `1`', client/src/exec.rs:167:9
note: run with `RUST_BACKTRACE=1` environment variable to display a backtrace
```

just like the case, when I type 1; the consdb will crush, it's very wired that it should just report a sql parse error but not crash.

```
CnosDB CLI v2.3.2
Input arguments: Args { host: "localhost", port: 8902, user: "root", password: None, private_key_path: None, database: "public", tenant: "cnosdb", precision: None, target_partitions: None, stream_trigger_interval: None, data_path: None, file: [], rc: None, format: Table, quiet: false, write_line_protocol: None, use_ssl: false, use_unsafe_ssl: false, cacert: [], chunked: false }
public ❯ 1;
error: sql parse error
```

Comment: Sounds like a bug, maybe you could report it to the project's issue tracker?  Would be nice to include follow up here (e.g. url of issue and what they think of it) in case a search engine leads them to this page